# How to get integer from CCArray - cocos2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

i have a CCArray

```
    CCArray *indexs;
```

then i add a integer into it

```
    int x = 0;
    [indexs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:x]];
```

then i want to get this integer from this CCArray

```
    id temp1 = [indexs objectAtIndex:0];
    int firstOne = (int) temp1;
```

then i try using CCLOG

```
    CCLOG(@"%d", firstOne);
```

it shows a random number in the terminal, then i try

```
    CCLOG(@"%@", firstOne);
```

it shows 0 in the terminal, and i tried to pass firstOne into a function, firstOne's value is not 0, then how can i get a integer value from my CCArray? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code as,

int firstOne = [temp1 intValue];